# « Comme qui dirait » : vu son origine, pourquoi le pronom relatif ?

Tags: locutions, pronoms-relatifs, origine-ou-raison, linguistique, évolution

On a la locution adverbiale populaire — *comme qui dirait* — signifiant « comme il semble » sur Wiktionnaire, « pour ainsi dire » chez [Larousse](http://%20pour%20ainsi%20dire.), [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/comme) ; provenant de « comme si on disait », qui marque « l'approximation, une sorte de synonyme d'*à peu près, pour ainsi dire, en quelque sorte*. » (*Le bon usage*, Grevisse et Goosse, éd. Duculot, 14<sup>e</sup>, § 1112 b).

Pourquoi ce [marqueur discursif](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marqueur_de_discours) comporte-t-il un pronom relatif (*qui*) s'il provient de « comme si on disait » ; est-ce tributaire d'une évolution du verbe (*dire*) ou d'une langue écrite [plus ancienne](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/47127/comme-qui-dirait-vu-son-origine-pourquoi-le-pronom-relatif#comment95617_47127) et le cas échéant pourquoi avait-on cette particularité ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il s'agit ici d'un emploi ancien du relatif *qui*. Au départ, l'expression *comme qui dirait* a le sens de « comme si l’on disait ».

Dans une note historique au sujet de *qui* Grevisse<sup>1</sup> précise que :

> Au moyen âge et jusqu'au XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle on employait communément un *qui* indéfini et suppositif au sens de « si l'on » ou de « si quelqu'un » ***Ki**<sup>2</sup> lui véist Sarrazins desmembrer (...) De bon vassal li poüst remembrer* [si quelqu'un l'avait vu démembrer les sarrazins, il aurait pu se souvenir d'un bon vassal] (*Chanson de Roland* 1970-72). — *C’est une vaine étude, **qui** veut ; mais **qui** veut aussi, c’est une étude de fruit inestimable*. (Montaigne, *Essais*)
> [...]
> Cet usage se retrouve dans la locution *comme qui dirait* et dans l'ancien dicton *Tout vient à point **qui** sait attendre.* La valeur de *qui* n'étant plus comprise on a dit *Tout vient à point **à qui** sait attendre*<sup>3</sup>.

[Christiane Marchello-Nizia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christiane_Marchello-Nizia) dans son *[Histoire de la langue française aux XIV<sup>e</sup> et XV<sup>e</sup> siècles](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_langue_fran%C3%A7aise_aux_XIVe_et_XVe_si/ACzMHAAACAAJ?hl=fr)* dit :

> Il y a en moyen français (comme en ancien français) une construction très vivante où *qui* n'a pas d'antécédent précisé, où il est en quelque sorte un relatif indéfini. On peut distinguer trois constructions : ou bien la relative a une fonction claire dans la principale (sujet du verbe par exemple) ; ou bien la relative est reprise par un pronom (*il* ou *on*) dans la principale ; ou bien la personne ou l'objet représenté par *qui* est absolument absent de la principale (c'est alors que l'on a recours à la traduction « si on... »).

C'est ce dernier cas qui nous intéresse ici et l'auteure donne en exemple :

> qui me paiast je m'en alasse<sup>4</sup> (*Farce de Maitre Pathelin*, v. 603)

Pour finir je renvoie à une communication faite par Sonia Gómez-Jordana Ferary au colloque international *Ci-Dit | Discours rapporté, citation et pratiques sémiotiques*  qui s'est tenu en 2009 :  [L’évolution de *comme qui dirait* en français](http://revel.unice.fr/symposia/cidit/index.html?id=496) où l'auteure expose l'« évolution sémantique et syntaxique tendant vers une plus grande subjectivité » du marqueur *comme qui dirait*.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> *Le bon usage*, (10<sup>e</sup> édition, § 541).</sup>
<sup><sup>2</sup> Graphie de *qui* en ancien français. (Voir [dictionnaire historique de l'ancien langage françois](http://micmap.org/dicfro/introduction/dictionnaire-lacurne))</sup> 
<sup><sup>3</sup> Au sujet de l'évolution du sens de ce proverbe on peut lire [l'article](https://www.persee.fr/doc/roma_0035-8029_1884_num_13_50_6318) qui lui est consacré dans la revue *Romania* « Tout vient à point qui sait attendre » (A. Delboulle, 1884, 50-51 p. 425-426).</sup>  
<sup><sup>4</sup> *Si on me payait, je m'en irais*. (Notre traduction)</sup>

Comment: @EylaChu-Generis Je me sens aussi moins ignorante après avoir répondu. Le sens de *qui* chez Montaigne résonnait encore quelque peu via de vagues souvenirs de lycée mais j'ai dû approfondir.  Voir aussi le n° 2/2015 de la revue «  Langue Française » co-dirigé par Sonia Gómez-Jordana Ferary avec un dossier *Dire et ses marqueurs*,  tous les articles sont [librement téléchargeables](https://www.cairn.info/revue-langue-francaise-2015-2.htm), et elle y publie *Dans la famille des comme on dit, qui dit quoi ? Polyphonie et médiativité chez comme qui dirait, comme disait l’autre, comme tu dis*.